# Jekyll: use regex/wildcards in _config.yml?

Tags: jekyll

I'm organizing my images and other assets with one directory per post, like this: `/assets/blog/[post date]/`. I'm using a responsive image plugin, so I can exclude images in that folder from the build like this:

> exclude: ["/assets/blog/*.jpg", "/assets/blog/*.png"]

Now I also have assets that are not parsed by the plugin (OG and Twitter card images), so I need those to be copied to the build. How can I add a pattern for those files to include those files?

Example:
Exclude all images in /assets/blog/ and its sub directories, except those in /assets/blog/[date]/OG-And-Twitter/

I tried to use regex:

> exclude: "/assets/blog/????-??-??/[\w|-]+.png"

But that didn't work.

Comment: I no longer have the need for an answer, as I found out that jekyll-picture-tag (the image plugin) can also render image URIs without the html tags around them. That allows me to have the OG and Twitter card images parsed by the plugin. Now I can just exclude all images in the /assets/blog/ directory.

As this question got an upvote, I'm not closing it though.